# defining and using classes in modules for Python

Tags: python, class, module

I have the module Test.py with class test inside the module. Here is the code:

```
class test:

    SIZE = 100;
    tot = 0;

    def __init__(self, int1, int2):
        tot = int1 + int2;

    def getTot(self):
        return tot;

    def printIntegers(self):
        for i in range(0, 10):
            print(i);
```

Now, at the interpreter I try:

```
>>> import Test
>>> t = test(1, 2);
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    t = test(1, 2);
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Class names should start with capital letter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to access the class like so:

```
Test.test
```

If you want to access the class like you tried to before, you have two options:

```
from Test import *
```

This imports everything from the module. However, it isn't recommended as there is a possibility that something from the module can overwrite a builtin without realising it.

You can also do:

```
from Test import test
```

This is much safer, because you know which names you are overwriting, assuming you are actually overwriting anything.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't say "because you know you're not overwriting anything", this isn't explicitly true. I would say "because you know which names you happen to be overwriting, assuming you are overwriting them".

Answer (score 1):

Your question has already been answered by @larsmans and @Votatility, but I'm chiming in because nobody mentioned that you're [violating Python standards with your naming convention](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#package-and-module-names).

Modules should be all lower case, delimited by underscores (optional), while classes should be camel-cased. So, what you *should* have is:

test.py:

```
class Test(object):
    pass
```

other.py

```
from test import Test
# or 
import test
inst = test.Test()
```

Comment: what is the pass keyword here?

Comment: It declares a class that inherits from ``object`` but doesn't do anything else (empty declaration). Definitely not something that should be used in practice, but good for demos such as this.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `import Test`, you can access the class as `Test.test`. If you want to access it as `test`, do `from Test import test`.